# Return boolean is view is visible

Tags: android-espresso

If I want to check is view is display I use this Espresso's test:

```
  @Test
    fun toolbar_menu_addTrader_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.add_trader))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

Nice.

But sometimes I need to return **true** when view is visible and else return **false** when not visible.

Is it possible by Espresso?

Answer (score 1):

I never found another solution to this, so this is an adaptation of what I did. I **believe** it's working for my purposes:

```
@Test
fun toolbar_menu_addTrader_isDiplayed() {
  // grab a nullable reference to the "add trader" button
  val button: ViewInteraction? = onView(withId(R.id.add_trader))
  // return whether it is null or not
  return button == null
}
```